# passing 4 items in as parameters not working

Tags: javascript, function

So I was to create a function `makeFunction (width, height, symbol, zigZag )` where `width` is the characters width, that repeats `height` times using `symbol` as the character, and `zigZag` is a boolean value to determine whether the pattern starts with a "zig" or "zag".

The output should look like this for `true`:

```
makeFunction( 4, 2, "#", true );
#
##
####
###
##
#
#
##
###
####
###
##
#
```

and for `false`:

```
makeFunction( 4, 2, "#", false );
####
###
##
#
#
##
###
####
###
##
#
```

whenever I try to run the script, it say `undefined` and am not sure what's missing. Here's my code http://jsfiddle.net/u6mjm/5/

Comment: FYI, `createLine` does isn't actually using it's `height` parameter.

Comment: There is no `makeFunction`, you mean `makeZigZag`?

Comment: The `customJS.get` function is giving you an element, but you are using it as if it returns that element's value.

Answer (score 1):

You had many, many problems.  I have fixed them all.

```
var width = customJS.get("width");
```

should be

```
var width = customJS.get("width").value;
```

I also cast to number and boolean depending upon how they are supposed to be used.

You were recreating `allLines` *inside* the `height` loop, but it should be outside.

You were not properly passing in or using `zigZag`.

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/u6mjm/6/